# Run jekyll build Command with Different url Flag

Tags: jekyll

My current `_config.yml` file looks like this:

```
#Site settings
...
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog/
url: "http://10.0.1.9:3000" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
...

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
safe: true
lsi: false
highlighter: true
keep_files: [public]
exclude: [src, lib, node_modules, bower.json, Gemfile, gulpfile.js, package.json, README.md]
```

I've got my `url` currently set to my local server, where I serve my Jekyll site for local development.

When building for production however, I have to keep manually changing this url to the url of my remote server before running `jekyll build`. Is there a way I can pass my remote url alongside the `jekyll build` command to build a site with the correct remote paths?

Something like so:

```
jekyll build --url mysite.com
```

Any help is appreciated with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your production url in `_config.yml` eg: `url: toto.com`.

Create a `_config_dev.yml` that will be used to override values in development.

In you case

```
url: "http://10.0.1.9:3000"
```

Development build is launched with :

```
jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml
```

Values in the last config file in the command will override those in first file.

and production build with `jekyll build`.

See Jekyll documentation http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#build-command-options configuration paragraphe.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll give this a try when I'm back home. One question, though — why do you have to add `_config.yml` to the command?

Comment: This is the order. Take file1, then override with file2, ans so on. You can have more than to files in the list and then create different configurations for dev, integration, production, CI, testing ...

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for this. Hopefully it helps others.